# Como encerrar um audio em execução

Tags: android

Estou criando uma aplicação que executa um som ou uma música, mas não consigo fazer o som parar. Desta forma sou obrigado a interromper o aplicativo manualmente para que o som pare. Como posso parar a música ao apertar um botão?

O código que estou usando é este:

```
public void repro(View view){

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.som); mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    mp.release(); }

            }); mp.start();}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `MediaPlayer` tem métodos [`pause()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#pause()) e [`stop()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop()) que servem para pausar e parar a execução do áudio, respectivamente.

O problema aqui é que você está criando o `MediaPlayer` como uma variável local ao seu método. Com isso, você está deixando ele "vazar". Em vez de declará-lo nesse método, declare-o como um membro da `Activity` e apenas inicialize-o dentro do método. Feito isso, digamos que seu botão de pausar se chame `pausarButton` e seu MediaPlayer continue se chamando `mp`, então faça algo assim:

```
pausarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp.pause();
    }
});
```

Claro que isso é só o começo. Tem outras coisas com as quais se preocupar, como em liberar o MediaPlayer com `release()` quando não for mais usar (o que pode não ser apenas quando o áudio acabar) e cuidar para que o áudio não reinicie ao rotacionar a tela.

Comment: Olá Pablo, primeiramente muito obrigado, sua ajuda foi muito importante.

Comment: Seguindo suas orientações consegui  adicionar um botão "pausar "e o "parar",  somente o "pausar" funcionou corretamente, o problema foi que, quando o som era interrompido utilizando o botão "parar" não era possivil iniciar o som novamente,  mas não tem problema, com o botão "pausar" funcionando é o que importa.

Answer (score 0):

Com minhas as alteraçôes meu código ficou assim:

```
    Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botão_play);
        Button pausar = (Button) findViewById (R.id.botão_pause);

    final   MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.som);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
        @Override
      public void onClick(View v){
            mp.start();}});

        pausar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override
     public void onClick(View v){
                mp.pause();
      }
});}
```